# Setting a reference number and comparing that to other data in textfile

Tags: c#, interaction, eye-tracking

The project is based on Eye Tracker. Let me brief the idea behind the project to understand my problem better.

I have the hardware of Tobii C eye tracker. This eye tracker will be able to give out coordinates of the X, Y of where I am looking at. But this device is very sensitive. When I look at 1 point, the eye tracker will send out many different data of coordinates but within `± 100` range which I found out. Even though you are staring at 1 point, your eyes keep moving, therefore giving out many data. This many data (float numbers) are then saved in a text file. Now I only need 1 data (X coordinate) which signifies the 1 point I am staring instead of the many data which are within the `± 100` range and move it to a new text file.

I have no idea how I should code to do that.

These are the `float` numbers in the text file.

```
200
201
198
202
250
278
310
315
360
389
500
568
579
590
```

When I stare at point 1, the data are `200-300`, which are within the `± 100` range. I wanna set the `200` as reference point subtracts itself with the next number and check if the resultant value within `100`, if it is, remove them. The reference point should keep doing that to the following numbers until it reaches outside the `± 100` range. Once outside the `100` range, now the number is `310`, then now this number is the next reference point and do the same and subtract with the following numbers below and check if the resultant value within `100`. Once outside the `100` range, the next number is `500`, now, that is the new reference point, and do the same. That is my objective. To put it to simpler terms, The reference points should be moved into a new file.

This is my code so far which get the gaze coordinates and stores them in a  text file.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using Tobii.Interaction;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{

class Program
{

    private static void programintro()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press Any Keys To Start");
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        programintro();
        Console.ReadKey();
        double currentX = 0.0;
        double currentY = 0.0;
        double timeStampCurrent = 0.0;
        double diffX = 0.0;
        double diffY = 0.0;
        int counter = 0;
        var host = new Host();
        host.EnableConnection();
        var gazePointDataStream = host.Streams.CreateGazePointDataStream();
        gazePointDataStream.GazePoint((gazePointX, gazePointY, timestamp) =>

        {
            diffX = gazePointX - currentX;
            diffY = gazePointY - currentY;
            currentX = gazePointX;
            currentY = gazePointY;
            timeStampCurrent = timestamp;
            if (diffX > 100 || diffX <= -100 || diffY >= 100 || diffY <= -100)
            {
                counter++;
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C: \\Users\\Student\\Desktop\\FYP 2019\\ConsoleApp1\\ConsoleApp1\\Data\\TextFile1.txt", true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("Recorded Data " + counter + "\n=================================================================================================================\nX: {0} Y:{1}\nData collected at {2}", currentX, currentY, timeStampCurrent);
                    writer.WriteLine("=================================================================================================================");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Recorded Data " + counter + "\n=================================================================================================================\nX: {0} Y:{1}\nData collected at {2}", currentX, currentY, timeStampCurrent);
                Console.WriteLine("=================================================================================================================");
            }
        });
        //host.DisableConnection();
        while (true)
        {
            if (counter <  10)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {

                Environment.Exit(0);

            }
        }
```

> Now my Question is how do I code to read the text file and set a
>   reference number and subtracts itself with the next number and check
>   if the resultant value within `100` and have a new reference number if
>   it outside the `± 100` range. Those reference numbers are then stored in
>   a new text file.

Comment: Pull up, pull up! Before you start processing this data, you need to understand the physiological process behind it. Plot the time series of the x and y components. Does it look like a proper saccade and fixate sequence? Are there transient blink artefacts, or periods of smooth pursuit? Is the head fixed, or is the VOR operating? Visualise before processing. If you aren't dealing with artefacts, or understanding the rapid transients (saccadic/vestibular/blink), your prematurely processed data will be meaningless. Start here perhaps: https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/s13428-016-0738-9

Comment: Damnn, i pulled up to a stop. However yr words are alien to me

Comment: And therein lies the problem. Analysing eye tracking data requires some domain-specific knowledge before you start doing any signal processing (probably like any other biological signal).

Comment: aight, however what i did so far was correct right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample data here is the code to get only numbers which has 100+ difference.

> ```
> static void Main(string[] args)
> {
>   string filename = @"C:\PowershellScripts\test.txt"; // INPUT FILE
>   String outputFile = @"C:\PowershellScripts\result.txt"; // OUTPUT FILE
>
>   string[] data = File.ReadAllLines(filename); // READING FORM FILE
>   int TotalLine = data.Length; // COUNT TOTAL NO OF ROWS
>   List<string> FinalList = new List<string>(); // INITIALIZE LIST FOR FINAL RESULT
>
>   if (TotalLine <= 0) // CHECK IF FILE HAS NO DATA
>   {
>       Console.WriteLine("No Data found !");
>       return;
>   }
>
>   double CurrentNumber = double.Parse(data[0]), NextNumber = 0, diff = 0; // INITIALIZE OF LOCAL VARIABLES, CURRENT NUMBER = FIRST NO FROM FILE
>
>   for (int cntr = 1; cntr < TotalLine; cntr++) // FOR LOOP FOR EACH LINE
>   {
>       NextNumber = double.Parse(data[cntr]); //PARSING NEXT NO
>       diff = CurrentNumber - NextNumber; // GETTING DIFFERENCE
>
>       if (diff <= 100 && diff >= -100) // MATCH THE DIFFERENCE
>       {
>           continue; // SKIP THE LOGIC IF DIFF IS LESS THEN 100
>       }
>       else
>       {
>           FinalList.Add(CurrentNumber.ToString()); // ADDING THE NO TO LIST
>           CurrentNumber = NextNumber; // POINTING TO NEXT NO
>       }
>
>   }
>
>   FinalList.Add(CurrentNumber.ToString()); // ADDING LAST NO.
>   foreach (string d in FinalList) // FOR EACH LOOP TO PRINT THE FINAL LIST
>       Console.WriteLine(d);
>
>   File.WriteAllLines(outputFile, FinalList); // SAVING TO THE FILE
>
> }
> ```

The above program will generate the output is :

> ```
> 200
> 310
> 500
> ```

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for yr help, however it did not show any output when compiled

Comment: i did change my file path according to mine. but wdym by replace whole sample code with my main function. I did not add yr code together with mine. i wanna test it out separately. so i created a new program and add yr codes.

Comment: are you developing in Visual studio console application ?

Comment: Yes. I am doing in Visual studio console application

Comment: are you pressing ctrl+F5 ?

Comment: i press start, which is compile.

Comment: The program '[16152] ReadTextFile.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0). There wasnt any error, but this was said

Comment: I have edited my answer, check the screen shot of the outout.
or you can run .exe file from bin/debug folder.

Comment: I want to add this output to a new text file. I am able to do in yr code?

Comment: Please do reply once seen

Comment: Thanks sir, is it possible if you could explain the  the code line by line, like the meaning for using it

Comment: Please do reply once seen

Comment: Okay, will do that

Comment: Much appreciated

Comment: I have added the comments

Comment: Aights, thank you, i will try to understand the codes and get back to you later

Comment: for (int cntr = 1; cntr < TotalLine; cntr++)     and the purpose of this line, i dont quite understand

Comment: for (xxx) is iteration of all the lines from input file.. and diff is variable which holds a difference value.. NextNumber is variable to store next number until we change/add number to the list

Comment: what does the cntr stands for, like its purpose

Comment: its a loop variable...like repeat the loop from 1 to N times with increament of the cntr value..

Comment: aight, May i know why Next number is equal  to 0 and  the diff is 0

Comment: its initial default value assigned to the variable,, you can remove = 0. Its a optional..

Comment: (int cntr = 1; cntr < TotalLine;  how about this, why cntr  equals to 1 and it is less than total number of rows

Comment: your reply will be much appreciated

Comment: bcoz we are  reading first and last lines are setting separately .

Comment: alright, thanks for guiding me throughout the whole code

Comment: appreciate your speedy replies. However i have more qn with the same concept which i will post seperately in another qn. Hope u will hang around mate

Comment: Hey buddy, it will be very helpful if u could see my new qn s i have used yr code as example to understand my new qn