# Referencing 2 coordinates and check differential value

Tags: c#, interaction

This question is a extension of a previous question i asked.

[Setting a reference number and comparing that to other data in textfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56625136/setting-a-reference-number-and-comparing-that-to-other-data-in-textfile)

I have a set of X & Y data coordinates in a text file.

```
Recorded Data 1

X: 1081.02409791506 Y:136.538121516361
Data collected at 208786.9115


Recorded Data 2

X: 1082.82841293328 Y:139.344405668078
Data collected at 208810.0446

Recorded Data 4

X: 1525.397051187 Y:1163.1786031393
Data collected at 245756.8823

Recorded Data 5

X: 1524.98201445054 Y:1166.38589429581
Data collected at 245769.489

Recorded Data 6

X: 509.002294087998 Y:913.213486303154
Data collected at 277906.6251

Recorded Data 7

X: 479.826998339658 Y:902.689393940613
Data collected at 277912.9958
```

I wanna set the first set of data which is `X: 1081.02409791506 Y:136.538121516361` as reference point, then it subtracts itself with the next set of data X & Y respectively and check if the resultant value within `100` for both X & Y differential value, if it is, continue the operation. The reference point should keep doing that to the following numbers until it reaches outside the `± 100 range`. Once outside the `100 range`, now the set of data is `X: 1525.397051187 Y:1163.1786031393` because the differential value of 1st data and this data is over `100`, then now this set of data is the next reference point and do the same and subtract with the following data below and check if the resultant value within `100`. Once outside the `100 range`, the next number is `X: 509.002294087998 Y:913.213486303154`, now, that is the new reference point, and do the same. That is my objective. To put it to simpler terms, The reference points should be moved into a new file.

This code is able to do the above but only for numbers shown below.

```
278
299
315
360
389
400
568
579
```

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ReadTextFile
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {       string inputFile = @"C:\Users\Student\Desktop\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Data\TextFile.txt"; // INPUT FILE
                string outputFile = @"C:\Users\Student\Desktop\Test.txt";  // OUTPUT FILE

                string[] data = File.ReadAllLines(inputFile);  // READING FORM FILE
                int TotalLine = data.Length;  // COUNT TOTAL NUMBER OF ROWS
                List<string> FinalList = new List<string>();  // INITIALIZE LIST FOR FINAL RESULT

            double CurrentNumber = double.Parse(data[0]), NextNumber, diff;  // INITIALIZE OF LOCAL VARIABLES, CURRENT NUMBER = FIRST NUMBER FROM FILE

            for (int cntr = 1; cntr < TotalLine; cntr++) // FOR LOOP FOR EACH LINE
            {
                    NextNumber = double.Parse(data[cntr]);  //PARSING NEXT NUMBER
                    diff = CurrentNumber - NextNumber;  // GETTING DIFFERENCE

                   if (diff <= 100 && diff >= -100)  // MATCH THE DIFFERENCE
                   {
                        continue;  // SKIP THE LOGIC IF DIFFERENCE IS LESS THEN 100
                   }
                   else
                   {
                        FinalList.Add(CurrentNumber.ToString());  // ADDING THE NUMBER TO LIST
                        CurrentNumber = NextNumber;  // POINTING TO NEXT NUMBER
                   }

            }
                FinalList.Add(CurrentNumber.ToString());  // ADDING LAST NUMBER
                foreach (string d in FinalList)  // FOR EACH LOOP TO PRINT THE FINAL LIST
                Console.WriteLine(d);
                File.WriteAllLines(outputFile, FinalList);  // SAVING TO THE FILE


        }
```

How do i do the same for 2 coordinates?

1st condition: At least 1 differential value of X or Y is outside the `± 100 range`, that set of data is the new reference data.

2nd condition: If both x and Y differential value is within `± 100 range`, we must continue the operation.

Comment: You have a file for each coordinate type, one for X and one for Y?

Comment: nope, the one i showed is in 1 text file

Comment: how does that file look? like the code posted above? with header `Recorded Data´ and blank lines etc... ?

Comment: i have edited it in right now , pls see the question again

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution, provided the source file content is as stated above:

> Recorded Data 1
>
> X: 1081.02409791506 Y:136.538121516361
>   Data collected at 208786.9115
>
> Recorded Data 2
>
> X: 1082.82841293328 Y:139.344405668078
>   Data collected at 208810.0446
>
> ..

and the target file as follows:

> X: 1081.02409791506 Y:136.538121516361
>   X: 1525.397051187 Y:1163.1786031393
>   ..

#### Solution

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var points = ParseFromFile(
                @"C:\Users\Student\Desktop\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Data\TextFile.txt");

            RenderToFile(
                @"C:\Users\Student\Desktop\Test.txt",
                Merge(points).ToArray());
        }

        static void RenderToFile(string fileName, (double x, double y)[] points)
        {
            var formatProvider = new CultureInfo("en-US", false);
            var builder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var point in points)
            {
                builder.Append(
                    $"X: {point.x.ToString(formatProvider)} Y:{point.y.ToString(formatProvider)}");
            }
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, builder.ToString());
        }

        static (double x, double y)[] ParseFromFile(string fileName)
        {
            return Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName)).ToArray();
        }

        static IEnumerable<(double x, double y)> Merge((double x, double y)[] points)
        {
            points = points ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(points));
            if (points.Length == 0) yield break;
            var std = 100;
            var current = points[0];
            if (points.Length == 1)
            {
                yield return current;
                yield break;
            }
            for (var i = 1; i < points.Length; i++)
            {
                var dx = Math.Abs(points[i].x - current.x);
                var dy = Math.Abs(points[i].y - current.y);

                if (dx <= std && dy <= std)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                yield return current;
                current = points[i];
            }
            yield return current;
        }

        static IEnumerable<(double x, double y)> Parse(string raw)
        {
            var formatProvider = new CultureInfo("en-US", false);
            var pattern = new Regex(@"^[Xx][:] (?<x>\d*([.]\d+)?) [Yy][:](?<y>\d*([.]\d+)?)$");
            raw = raw ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(raw));
            foreach (var line in raw.Split(
                Environment.NewLine, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(
                line => line.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("x")))
            {
                var match = pattern.Match(line);
                var xToken = match.Groups["x"].Value.Trim();
                var yToken = match.Groups["y"].Value.Trim();
                var x = double.Parse(xToken, formatProvider);
                var y = double.Parse(yToken, formatProvider);
                yield return (x: x, y: y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Explained

First we need to parse the data.

The format provider is required to parse a `double` correctly from a fixed string with decimal seperator `.`.

```
// can parse 1525.397051187, but not 1525,397051187
// en-US is the format you comply with
// 'false' is required to use the default culture settings, not any user overrided
var formatProvider = new CultureInfo("en-US", false);
```

The pattern ensures we parse the `x` and `y` coordinate correctly.

```
// X: 1525.397051187 Y:1163.1786031393
// we use named groups to capture x (?<x>\d*([.]\d+)?)
//                            and y (?<y>\d*([.]\d+)?)
var pattern = new Regex(@"^[Xx][:] (?<x>\d*([.]\d+)?) [Yy][:](?<y>\d*([.]\d+)?)$");
```

Once parsed, we can *merge* (x,y) coordinates based on your specification. `std` is the allowed standard deviation for our deltas (`dx`, `dy`).

```
var dx = Math.Abs(points[i].x - current.x);
var dy = Math.Abs(points[i].y - current.y);

if (dx <= std && dy <= std)
{
    continue;
}
```

A note on `IEnumerable<T>`:

Using this as return value allows us to use the `yield` syntax. This is called a generator function.

A note on value tuple `(double x, double y)`:

We can use named tuples to avoid creating 'stupid' intermediate classes.

Comment: Consider an adding an explanation to your approach

Comment: Sure I didn't know this was expected at this site.

Comment: thanks for the effort, however it will be better if we can read from the textfile, as there will be many more set of data( eg. 50+) in the textfile instead of listing out the set of data in the code itself. For example, in my code, i read the datas from my text file, instead of listing down

Comment: Reading from text file is just passing `File.ReadAllText()` to my `Parse` method. Do you want I add code to read and write to/from text file?

Comment: i have added a picture, there are some pointers not declared i think

Comment: I noticed your picture. You need to update your version of .NET Framework. Which version are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 version

Comment: In your project properties, which version of the framework is used?

Comment: Value tuples are tuple types introduced in the .NET Framework 4.7

Comment: Either you update the version or you refactor the code to replace `(double, double)`with a custom class or a `Tuple<double, double>`.

Comment: @dfhwze +1 for tuples